# Add a movieclip but make sure it isn't in the same place as another movieclip. (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I have [this](http://www.fastswf.com/cq_200M) where you add movieclips by clicking, but it is unefficient and doesn't have some functionality that I want, I need to only add the movieclip if no other movieclip is in the same place.

```
private function onClick():void
        {
            if(placesound==false)
            {
                placepixel.play();
                placesound = true;
            }
            if(erasetrue==false)
            {
                var pixel = new Pixel();
                pixel.x = 0;
                pixel.y = 0;
            }
            if(mouseY>30 && irontrue==true)
            {
                //var pixel = new Pixel();
                pixel.x=(Math.round(mouseX/5)*5)-2.5;
                pixel.y=(Math.round(mouseY/5)*5)-2.5;
                pixel.graphics.beginFill(0x999999);
                pixel.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 5, 5);
                pixel.graphics.endFill();
                pixel.type=0;
                pix.push(pixel);
                //addChild(pixel);
            }
            if(mouseY>30 && woodtrue==true)
            {
                //var pixel = new Pixel();
                pixel.x=(Math.round(mouseX/5)*5)-2.5;
                pixel.y=(Math.round(mouseY/5)*5)-2.5;
                pixel.graphics.beginFill(0x996600);
                pixel.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 5, 5);
                pixel.graphics.endFill();
                pixel.type=3;
                pix.push(pixel);
                //addChild(pixel);
            }
            if(erasetrue==true)
            {
                for (i=pix.length-1; i>=0; i--)
                {
                    if(pix[i].x==(Math.round(mouseX/5)*5)-2.5 && pix[i].y==(Math.round(mouseY/5)*5)-2.5)
                    {
                        removeChild(pix[i]);
                        pix.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(mouseY>30 && springtrue==true)
            {
                //var pixel = new Pixel();
                pixel.x=(Math.round(mouseX/5)*5)-2.5;
                pixel.y=(Math.round(mouseY/5)*5)-2.5;
                pixel.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
                pixel.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 5, 5);
                pixel.graphics.endFill();
                pixel.type=1;
                pix.push(pixel);
                //addChild(pixel);
            }
            if(mouseY>30 && portaltrue==true)
            {
                //var pixel = new Pixel();
                pixel.x=(Math.round(mouseX/5)*5)-2.5;
                pixel.y=(Math.round(mouseY/5)*5)-2.5;
                pixel.graphics.beginFill(0x9999FF);
                pixel.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 5, 5);
                pixel.graphics.endFill();
                pixel.type=2;
                pix.push(pixel);
                //addChild(pixel);
            }
            if(erasetrue==false)
            {
                addChild(pixel);
            }
        }
```

I want to somehow only run the last if (the one that addChilds the pixel.) only if no other movieclip (see the array "pix") has is already in the spot it would be placed in. (I round the mouse before placing it.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Spoilers failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the pix array to see if any of the pixels in the array match the x and y coordinates of the new pixel object. If not, the pixel should be added.

So instead of your final if statement:

```
...
if(erasetrue==false){
    var canPlace:Boolean = true;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < pix.length; i++){
        var placedPixel:Pixel = pix[i] as Pixel;
        if(pixel.x == placedPixel.x && pixel.y == placedPixel.y){
             canPlace = false;
        }

    }

    if(canPlace){
        addChild(pixel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized I have a worthless boolean that I was about to get rid of, looks like i have a use for it.